# Solving linear program with 1 quadratic constraint complexity

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming, qclp

Consider the following linear program,

$$\min y \\
xc_1 \leq c_2 + yz,\\
x = x_1 + \dots + x_n,\\
z \leq x_1 + x_2, \\
z \leq x_2 + x_3, \\
\vdots\\
z \leq x_{n-1} + x_n, \\
x,x_1, \dots, x_n,y,z \geq 0
$$ 
where $c_1, c_2$ are constants. This is an example of quadratically constrained linear program where I have 1 quadratic constraint. I wish to find out if this problem is NP-Hard or not. The quadratic constraint can be expressed in the form $\vec{y}M\vec{y}^T$ where $M$ for my problem is not positive semidefinite (and thus, non-convex).

Listing the questions:

1. Can this problem be transformed into a linear program by taking logs?
2. Is there any literature reference or reduction showing that linear programs with non-convex quadratic constraints is an NP-Hard problem?

Comment: QCPs are "easy" when convex, and difficult when not.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I need a reference for that :-)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2433177/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/39108/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following linear program - and then you write down a bilinear program.

Good news though is that you easily can solve this by bisection in $y$, meaning that 
complexity is complexity of solving a linear program, times a constant which is logarithmic in the desired precision (as you half the interval for every linear program you solve)

EDIT: Good or bad news is that the problem can be solved analytically, the optimal value approaches $0$ but that is done by letting half of the $x_i$ tend to infinity. Let $x_i$ be $\mu$ for even $i$ and $0$ for odd $i$. The constraints involving $z$ then all simplify to $z\leq \mu$. The constraints will be active at optimality (otherwise $z$ can be made larger and thus $y$ smaller), hence $z = \mu$. The first constraint simplifies to $(c_1\mu \lfloor n/2 \rfloor -c_2)/\mu\leq y$, or equivalently we are minimizing $c_1 \lfloor n/2 \rfloor -c_2/\mu$. We have $\mu \geq 0$ and for the problem to make sense $c_2\leq 0$ (otherwise the problem is trivial as one could take the zero solution.)

Hence, the infimum is  $c_1 \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ which is approached when $\mu \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I was not aware of bilinear programs! Seems like a quadratic function is also a bilinear function. Could you clarify how can I incorporate the interval halving in this program since the value y can take does not have an upper bound apriori.

Comment: Bilinear is simply a special case of quadratic. To find an initial upper bound, simply solve a linear problem without the first constraint where you maximize $z$. If $xc_1 \leq c_2$, the solution to the original problem is $y=0$. If the problem is unbounded, then the problem is ill-posed as $y = 0_{+}$ is optimal. Otherwise, an initial upper bound can be computed from $(x c_1-c_2)/z$.

Comment: Before I accept your answer, I am still at loss on how do I actually incorporate the range of y in the program. Adding a constraint of $y \leq c_3$ does not make the program linear. Could you give a small example of the program which is LP when y is bounded? I looked for cutting plane method but could not convince myself how does it make the program linear.

Comment: When you perform the bisection, you solve a series of linear programs where $y$ has been fixed to the value currently tested in the bisection

Comment: Note that $x=z=y=0$ is optimal unless $c_2 < 0$

Comment: Let me be more specific. Suppose that $ 0 \leq y \leq 100$ after finding the upper bound. What is the next LP that I would solve? Fix $y \geq 50$?

Comment: You perform a bisection so you solve LP with $y$ fixed to 50. If that leads to infeasibility, you know that 50 is a new lower bound instead of $0$. If it leads to feasibility, you know 50 is a new upper bound instead of 100. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I would probaly minimize $(z-1)^2$ or something like that instead to avoid unboundedness and get an initial guess

Comment: By the structure of my problem, all of the variables are bounded from above and there is a guarantee that a solution exists. So an initial guess is no problem. I didn't expect this program to be solvable in quasi polynomial time though!

Comment: By looking at the solution, you will see that you can compute the solution analytically

Comment: Yes, but $z$ is unbounded in the linear program where you skip the first constraint, which I proposed as the first way to get an initial bound. Better to solve a problem where you get a bounded $z$ by consttruction

Comment: Do you have a proof that the optimal value of the objective function is monotonic in the value of $y$?

Comment: Added a complete proof of analytical solution